# Bundle wxPython App for Mac App Store without ppc code (binary)

Tags: python, wxpython, mac-app-store, py2app, universal-binary

I have delevloped (for the past 7 years) a wxPython App that would like to distribute thru the Mac App Store. I am using Python2.7 and wxPython2.9.4 (cocoa). The App is the bundled using py2app.
All looks good so far.
The problem is that Application Loader rejects the Package because py2app bundles this dynamic library "libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib" that obviously  contains ppc code and submissions must be intel only.

How can I bundle this app without the ppc code?

The --arch="intel" argument for py2app does not solve this problem.

How can I achieve this? The rest of the bundle is OK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`lipo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html)?

```
lipo -remove ppc libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib -output libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.4.0.0.dylib.intel
```

you can then see if everything still works with the new output lib (renaming back to the original name of course)

If that is accepted by the loader you could add this to your build script so that ppc is removed after it is build each time.